# Mechanism to force iTunes Match to not match/upload tracks

Tags: apple-music, itunes-match

I've been using Apple Music for almost ten years now, and for the most part, I have no complaints.

One issue I've run into though is iTunes Match will match a track, and because of the ever shifting licensing/rights landscape, the track will be removed from Apple Music. Fortunately Apple Music/iTunes records which tracks are no longer available, but this has happened for about 100 tracks in my library now.

Has anyone else encountered this/figured out a workaround?